# C# adding lines from a text file to a listbox

Tags: c#

I have a text file that contains lines of text, I am trying to add certain line to a listbox if the next line meet the a condition for example

if the line starts with a # then add that line if the next line starts with a @ and all line after that that start with a @

```
#add this line
@add this line
@add this line
@add this line
#dont add because the next line is not a @
#dont add because the next line is not a @
#dont add because the next line is not a @
#dont add because the next line is not a @
#add this line
@add this line
@add this line
#dont add because the next line is not a @
#add this line
@add this line  
#add this line
@add this line
```

hope this makes scene any help would be great

Comment: [What have your tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why do you need such a crazy filtering scheme?!?

Answer (score 3):

Use String's StartsWith method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx

The whole your function will be like

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(yourpath);
var resultLines = new List<string>();
bool adding = false;
for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++)
{
    var line = lines[i];
    if((line.StartsWith("#") && i < lines.Length-1 && lines[i+1].StartsWith("@"))
       || adding && line.StartsWith("@"))
        adding = true;
    else if(i < lines.Length-1 && !lines[i+1].StartsWith("@"))
        adding = false;
    if(adding)
        resultLines.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: Wow that's ugly code, but it works and the original problem is real ugly too.  Probably some extra, well-named, variables could reduce some of the clutter.  +1 'cause it works perfectly.